# Finding duplicate entries in an Array - groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have a problem with groovy scripting. I am trying to run a script that points out the duplicate entries in an Array and put the duplicates in a new array

```
def i = 0
def j = 1

def result = []
def result2 = []
def list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10]

while ( i < list.size) {
    while ( j < list.size ) {
        
        if(list[j] == list[i]) {
            
            result.add(list[j])
            
        } else {
            j++
        }
    }
    
    i++
}

log.info ("While iteration ${result}")

def x = 1

for ( a in list) {
    while(x < list.size) {
        if ( a == list[x]) {
            result.add[x]
        } 
        x++
    }
}

log.info ("For iteration ${result2}")
```

I tried comparing values using "while" and "for (a in list)" iterations between but I didn't manage to create duplicate array.

I do not want the opposite approach by using the unique() function because it removes the duplicates that is not what I want

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the duplicated values, you could go with:

```
def list = [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10]

def duplicateEntries = list.countBy { it }
                           .findAll { it.value > 1 }
                           .collectMany { [it.key] * (it.value - 1) }

assert duplicateEntries == [4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10]
```

Or if you just want to know which they are, then:

```
def duplicateEntries = list.countBy { it }.findAll { it.value > 1 }*.key

assert duplicateEntries == [4, 5, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, no I was wondering what if I was comparing were strings instead of numbers?


`def texter = ["Honey", "Glaze", "Sweet", "Sweet", "Corny", "Mellow", "Syrup", "Maple", "Apple", "Apple", "Glycerine"]`

Comment: It will just work. Did you try?